# PROC SQL throwing error in cast statement at 'as' and alias at 'as'

Tags: sas

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT end_dt-start_dt as EXPOSURE,
 (CASE WHEN (EXPOSURE)<0 THEN 0 ELSE CAST(TRUNC((EXPOSURE)/30+0.99) as 
INTEGER)  END as bucket) FROM TABLE
```

This statement works fine in SQL but throws an error in proc sql at both 'as'.

Comment: In the future please include your errors/log at minimum and data that allows us to replicate the issues. You may have multiple errors depending, I've answered the most likely issue below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CAST is not a valid SAS SQL function. Use the appropriate SAS SQL function, in this case likely INT(), to convert calculation to an integer value.

If you'd like to use your DB SQL you need to use SAS SQL Pass Through which will pass the code directly to your database, but then the entire query must be valid on that database.

Answer (score 0):

**SAS** has attributes for every field like Length, Format, Informat. They help store, read and read from a data source.

Your `PROC SQL` would not require a type cast. Instead use FORMAT statement.

```
PROC SQL; SELECT end_dt-start_dt as EXPOSURE, CASE WHEN (EXPOSURE)<0 THEN 0 ELSE INT(TRUNC((EXPOSURE)/30+0.99)) END as bucket Format 8. FROM TABLE
```

Not sure or syntax of the whole statement as I couldn't get to test it, although the whole idea holds true.